# Polkadot version 36 - app_crypto! error (cannot find macro `format` in this scope)

Tags: substrate-node-template, versioning

When compiling version 36 substrate or cumulus I can see this error and not sure how to get rid of

```
error: cannot find macro `format` in this scope
  --> /Users/hotovo/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-56aa5b68bc705a80/8d5b532/primitives/consensus/aura/src/lib.rs:50:3
   |
50 |         app_crypto!(ed25519, AURA);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: consider importing this macro:
           scale_info::prelude::format
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::app_crypto_public_common_if_std` which comes from the expansion of the macro `app_crypto` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I tried in substrate repo to comment out those members and the compilation was successful. What could be wrong here? Thank you

```
#"bin/node-template/node",
#"bin/node-template/pallets/template",
"bin/node-template/runtime",
#"bin/node/bench",
#"bin/node/cli",
#"bin/node/test-runner-example",
#"bin/node/executor",
#"bin/node/primitives",
#"bin/node/rpc",
#"bin/node/rpc-client",
#"bin/node/runtime",
#"bin/node/testing",
#"bin/utils/chain-spec-builder",
#"bin/utils/subkey",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `Cargo.toml`.

If you missed any `"xxx/std"` feature.

Also, you could use subalfred.

https://subalfred.hack.ink/user/cli/check.html#features

Comment: I already using this subalfred feature but still I have this error.

Comment: Could you share your project?

Comment: I forgot to make this answer correct. Thanks